# Proving uniform convergence of a sequence of functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

I was wondering how to prove or disprove the following sequence of functions is uniformly convergent

$$\ f(n) = \frac{nt}{nt+1}, n≥1, t:[0,1] \to R$$

So far I have analyzed the limits at $t=0$ and $t=1$ and believe it to be point-wise convergent, but not uniformly convergent. However, I'm not sure how to prove this.

Also, how does the above sequence vary from

$$\ f(n) = \frac{nt}{n+t}, n≥1, t:[0,1] \to R$$
in regards to uniform convergence?

Comment: Maybe you mean $f(t)$ or $f_n(t)$, with $t \in [0, 1]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, right?

Answer (score 3):

Observe $$f_n(t)=\frac{nt}{nt+1}=\dfrac{t}{t+\dfrac{1}{n}}\to\begin{cases}0 , &t=0\\1, &t\neq0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

For $t$ fixed in $(0,1]$,

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(t)=1=f(t)$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(0)=0=f(0)$$

the pointwise limit $f$ is not continuous at $[0,1]$, the convergence is Not uniform since all $f_n$ are continuous at $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence

$$f_n(t) = \frac{nt}{nt+1}$$

converges (in a point-wise sense) to:

$$f(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if}~t=0\\
1 & \text{if}~0<t\leq 1
\end{cases}.$$

To check uniform convergence, you need to evaluate $d_n(t) = |f_n(t) - f(t)|$:

$$d_n(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if}~t=0\\
\displaystyle \frac{1}{nt+1} & \text{if}~0<t\leq 1
\end{cases}.$$

Notice that:

$$\sup_{t \in [0,1]} d_n(t) = 1,$$

which does not converge to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Therefore, convergence is not uniform.